# A concrete definition of generalized quaternion group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I just learned that
$$Q_{2^{n+1}}=\langle a,b\mid a^{2^n}=1,\ a^{2^{n-1}}=b^2,\ b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$$
is called a generalized quaternion group.
But is there a more concrete and intuitive way to define this, say, for $n=3$, like the standard quaternion group
$$Q_8=\{1,-1,i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}$$
when $n=2$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by concretely and intuitively. You can realize the generalized quaternion group as a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ by
$a = \begin{pmatrix}\zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \overline{\zeta} \end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, where $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i /2^n)$.
I mean, from the presentation, you can write all $2^{n+1}$ elements of the group:
$1, a, ..., a^{2^n-1}, b, ab, ..., a^{2^n-1}b$. Also, if $a = \exp(2\pi i /2^n)$ and $b = j$, you can realize it as a subgroup of $\mathbb H^\times$.

Comment: It is not perhaps immediately obvious from the presentation that the order of the group that it defines is $2^{n+1}$ (it is easy to see that it is at most that), and the realization as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb C})$ proves that it is.

Comment: You can think of these groups as being the dicyclic groups of order a power of two. That is, those groups which admit a non-split extension $1\rightarrow C_{2^n}\rightarrow G\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow 1$ where the action is inversion (here $C_m$ denotes the cyclic group of order $m$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about
$$Q_{16}=\{1,i,i^2,i^3,j,k,l,m,-1,-i,-i^2,-i^3,-j,-k,-l,-m\},$$
where
$$k\mathrel{\mathop:}=ij,\qquad l\mathrel{\mathop:}=i^2j,\qquad m\mathrel{\mathop:}=i^3j,$$
and
$$-1\mathrel{\mathop:}=i^4=j^2=k^2=l^2=m^2$$
is the unique element of order 2?

Comment: I am afraid that I prefer the original presentation!